# JdbcType quarkus dev mode

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, quarkus

I've a problem when I run "mvn quarkus:dev". The problem is:
"Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `org.myapp.model.Anagrafica`"

I tried a lot of solution (and I think the problem is the corrupt DB even if I tried to delete it e re-create it). My model class is like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Anagrafica {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String matrix;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate date;

    @OneToOne
    private Rec rec;

    @OneToOne
    private Ind ind;

}
```

application.properties:

```
`quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`
`quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=update`
```

Before today it was ok, but now I dunno why I've this problem.
Can someone help me? Thank u so much guys.